# Prioritzing acquisition of a fair ReentrantLock where it could potentially be locked

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, reentrantlock

I have a ReentrantLock that a bunch of operations are locking on, that was created as fair with `new ReentrantLock(true)`. Is there a way for a thread to "barge in" onto the lock and acquire it after it's released but before any other threads?

I have considered various combinations of timed and untimed `tryLock`:

- `tryLock()` by itself will barge in on the lock if it is already unlocked and threads are waiting, but will not wait for the lock to become available.
- The same method with the timeout is fair.
- Combining both won't work since if it's locked at the beginning the timeout-based tryLock will fall back to fair scheduling.

Or am I wrong?

Comment: Did you have a look at [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11683/reentrantlock-with-priorities-for-waiting-threads)?

Comment: @Domi I'll have to look. I ended up reworking my code yesterday to have lockfree priority operations, but the situation is likely to pop up again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.java#ReentrantLock.0sync), the `ReentrantLock` uses [`AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java#AbstractQueuedSynchronizer) as the actual thread queue implementation. Seeing how none of it's methods are overridable, you cannot do this easily, i.e. replace the standard thread queue with a **priority queue**.

But as it says in the documentation: "This class provides an efficient and scalable basis for synchronization in part by specializing its range of use to synchronizers that can rely on int state, acquire, and release parameters, and an internal FIFO wait queue. When this does not suffice, you can build synchronizers from a lower level using atomic classes, your own custom java.util.Queue classes, and LockSupport blocking support."

So that is what you need to do: Build your own lock. Your primary goal there is to let the `release` method use a priority queue to make the decision. If performance is not an issue, you can just use the standard [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) where you can just make its reads and writes thread-safe with `synchronized`, `ReentrantLock` or any other standard lock available. Thread-safe priority queues are hard to come by. However, if performance is important, [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.66.6665&rep=rep1&type=pdf) from 2003 might be of interest to you.

However, since the user can modify the thread's priority at any given time, it might be the easiest to just use a basic queue and use [stable sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) (as to not mess up order of threads with equal priority) before getting the next guy. Of course, performance will be bad if you want to use it for high-contention critical sections.

Comment: Domi: I'm not looking for a full priority queue. I'm looking for simply some sort of single override--not custom configurable priority levels. I guess I'll have to reimplement, though.

Comment: @hexafraction As I said, just use the standard PriorityQueue. The most basic implementation of a lock is actually pretty simple (you can just use a ReentrantLock or other lock to lock the queue when you access it).

Comment: @hexafraction I added another paragraph, in case you want to support this to work with `Thread.setPriority`.